# Equation for calculating the volume of liquid in an ellipsoid

Tags: calculus, geometry, analytic-geometry

I am looking for an equation to calculate the volume of liquid in an underground tank based on a depth reading.

The tank is an ellipsoid shape with the following dimensions:

```
X-Axis Radius:    30.425 cm
Y-Axis Radius:    30.425 cm
Z-Axis Radius:    60.95 cm
```

I am trying to find an equation that would provide the volume of liquid in liters at a specific depth:
For example:

```
When the tank is filled up with liquid to:
30cm (1/2 way) 
the volume of liquid would be around:  
120 Liters.

And when the tank if filled up to the top:
60cm
the volume would be around:  
240 Liters.
```

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the semi-axes (the 'radii') in each direction be $r_x$, $r_y$, and $r_z$, and let the depth of the liquid be $d$. Squeeze (or stretch) the ellipsoid into a sphere of unit radius, so that all of these are $1$; the depth of the liquid is then $d' = d/r_z$, and its volume is $\pi d'^2(3-d')/3$, as you know from [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18914/horizontal-tank-with-hemispherical-ends-depth-to-capacity-calculation). Now stretch (or squeeze) the sphere back into its original shape, thus expanding the volume of the liquid by a factor $r_xr_yr_z$.

Comment: Thank you Tony! That makes it quite clear for me. So the equation in its entirety would be: π * (d/rz)^2*(3−(d/rz))/3 * rx*ry*rz.

Comment: @Synergistca: Yes.